# Find for which $K$ the sum $(1^2+2^2+\ldots +K^2)\mid (1^4+2^4+\ldots + K^4)$, where $k \in \mathbb N$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find for which $k$ the sum $1^2+2^2+\ldots + K^2$ divides $1^4+2^4+\ldots + K^4$, where $K \in \mathbb N$

I am not sure if I should proceed by trial and error, but I would appreciate the help.

Comment: There are formulas for the sums of powers of the first $K$ integers. You can use these formulas for power 2 and 4, and see when the power 2 formula divides the power 4 formula.

Comment: I like to test these sorts of things with a few examples, say for $K=1..5$. You can then edit your post to show your work (which is expected on MSE) and ask for further direction. BTW for $K=1$ the assertion is true.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint :** $$ \sum n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$ and $$\sum n^4 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)}{30}=\sum n^2 \times \frac{(3n^2+3n-1)}{5}$$

Therefore you have to just find whenever $\dfrac{(3n^2+3n-1)}{5}$ is an integer.

Can you proceed now?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

There are [closed formulas for these sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples). From these follows

$$(1^2+2^2+....K^2)\cdot\frac{3K^2+3K-1}{5} =(1^4+2^4+...K^4)$$